# Can I combine small seed satchels?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Looked everywhere for this simple question.

I have 2 small seed satchels, is there anyway to combine them into one, so that there would be a +20 bonus. Or do you just upgrade one, and sell the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot combine two ammo-extention items. You can only upgrade single ones.